# How is this a coroutine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, coroutine

I'm trying to understand the coroutines in Python (and in general). Been reading about the theory, the concept and a few examples, but I'm still struggling. I understand the asynchronous model (did a bit of Twisted) but not coroutines yet.

One [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/26/python-3-an-intro-to-asyncio/) gives this as a coroutine example (I made a few changes to illustrate my problem):

```
async def download_coroutine(url, number):
    """
    A coroutine to download the specified url
    """
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    filename = os.path.basename(url)
    print("Downloading %s" % url)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as file_handle:
        while True:
            print(number) # prints numbers to view progress
            chunk = request.read(1024)
            if not chunk:
                print("Finished")
                break
            file_handle.write(chunk)
    msg = 'Finished downloading {filename}'.format(filename=filename)
    return msg
```

This is run with this

```
coroutines = [download_coroutine(url, number) for number, url in enumerate(urls)]
completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines)
```

Looking at generator coroutines examples I can see a few `yield` statements. There's nothing here, and urllib is synchronous, AFAIK.

Also, since the code is supposed to be asynchronous, I am expecting to see a series of interleaved numbers. (1, 4, 5, 1, 2, ..., "Finished", ...) . What I'm seeing is a single number repeating ending in a `Finished` and then another one (3, 3, 3, 3, ... "Finished", 1, 1, 1, 1, ..., "Finished" ...).

At this point I'm tempted to say the tutorial is wrong, and this is a coroutine just because is has async in front.

Comment: Yours is a co-routine *just* because you used `async def`. It is not a very cooperative one as it never yields to other co-routines. So yes, your analysis is correct.

Comment: I made a mistake when I originally wrote that tutorial. It has been updated to use `aiohttp`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *co* in *coroutine* stands for *cooperative*. Yielding (to other routines) makes a routine a co-routine, really, because only by yielding when waiting can other co-routines be interleaved. In the new `async` world of Python 3.5 and up, that usually is achieved by `await`-ing results from other coroutines.

By that definition, the code you found is *not* a coroutine. As far as *Python* is concerned, it is a coroutine *object*, because that's the type given to a function object created using `async def`.

So yes, the tutorial is.. unhelpful, in that they used entirely synchronous, uncooperative code inside a coroutine function.

Instead of `urllib`, an asynchronous HTTP library would be needed. Like [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
import aiohttp

async def download_coroutine(url):
    """
    A coroutine to download the specified url
    """
    filename = os.path.basename(url)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
                while True:
                    chunk = await resp.content.read(1024)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    fd.write(chunk)
    msg = 'Finished downloading {filename}'.format(filename=filename)
    return msg
```

This coroutine can yield to other routines when waiting for a connection to be established, and when waiting for more network data, as well as when closing the session again.

We could further make the file writing asynchronous, but that [has portability issues](https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty#filesystem); the [`aiofiles` project](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles/) library uses threads to off-load the blocking calls to. Using that library, the code would need updating to:

```
import aiofiles

async with aiofiles.open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    while True:
        chunk = await resp.content.read(1024)
        if not chunk:
            break
        await fd.write(chunk)
```

---

*Note*: the blog post has since been updated to fix these issues.

Comment: I am a long time python2.7 programmer, for some reason i have been avoiding the newer python. i found the original tutorial and these SO entries very helpful. I am puzzled that this question / answer doesn't have more upvotes.  Is the subject area that specialized?  Nice work!

Comment: @Greg: coroutines are a relatively new addition to Python, so not that many have worked with them yet.